# Roblox: MarketplaceService:PromptGamePassPurchase error

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have made a game pass, and in solo mode, if I check that the game pass (which I own) is owned, everything is fine. But when I test the game via the test tab, or upload it and connect with another account, the call in a server script:

```
clientWantsPass.OnServerEvent:connect(function(plr) 
    print("Prompting for purchase of " .. tostring(conf.changeSongPassID))
    MarketplaceService:PromptGamePassPurchase(plr,conf.changeSongPassID)
end)
```

Produces the output on the server:

```
Prompting for purchase of 1059063949
```

And on the client:

```
04:14:25.798 - PurchasePromptScript: getProductInfo failed because MarketplaceService:getProductInfo() failed because HTTP 0 (HTTP 400 (HTTP/1.1 400 BadRequest)) Make sure a valid ID was specified
```

The pass does exist, I made it. calls to

```
game:GetService("GamePassService"):PlayerHasPass(plr, conf.changeSongPassID)
```

Return true for my character, and false for people who haven't bought it yet. I've tested putting the call to PromptGamePassPurchase on the server side, or in a local script. Always the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [PromptPurchase](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/MarketplaceService/PromptPurchase)? According to the comments on [this ScriptingHelpers page](https://scriptinghelpers.org/questions/47769/not-able-to-prompt-gamepass-purchase), that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because Roblox messed up the Gamepasses, and now they're a seperate 'category'.

You could try by using PromptPurchase, like MoonRunestar said?